# How can I remove shadow from expansion panel (Vuetify)?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to remove the shadow from a Vuetify expansion panel. Currently, it looks like this:

[image: Expansion panel with shadow]

My code looks like this:

```
  <v-layout wrap justify-space-between>
    <v-flex xs12 pb-1>
      <v-card>
        <v-container pa-2>
          <v-expansion-panel expand pa-0>
            <v-expansion-panel-content>
              <template v-slot:header>
                <div>
                  {{ $t("var1") }}
                </div>
              </template>
              <v-layout row wrap>
                <v-flex xs12>
                  <v-text-field
                    class="right-input"
                    :label="$t('var2')"
                    value="600.00"
                    suffix="$"
                    disabled
                    flat
                  ></v-text-field>
                </v-flex>
              </v-layout>
            </v-expansion-panel-content>
          </v-expansion-panel>
        </v-container>
      </v-card>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
```

It is possible to remove the shadow from the expansion panel? I tried adding "flat" to the  tag but it didn't solve it. My goal is that, while expanded, it looks like a flat card. Thanks! :)

Comment: I actually want to remove all borders, make the panel completely flat

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set `elevation-0` class on `v-expansion-panel`.

Here is working example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oKjRpm?editors=1010

I'd rather avoid changing CSS, because it will remove all borders and shadows, on all expansion panels on all pages.

Comment: That's true, previous solution also works, but as this one doesn't modify the CSS is better :)

Comment: Is there also any way of modifying the header left and right margin without changing the CSS style?

Comment: You can use `Spacing helpers`. https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/spacing

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with vuetify 2.x. any tips?

Comment: For the ones trying with Vuetify 2.x the workaround that I've found is:
.v-expansion-panel:before {
  box-shadow: none !important;
}

Answer (score 11):

In Vuetify v.2 you can use the attribute `flat` in v-expansion-panels.
Documented here: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-expansion-panels/#flat

```
<v-expansion-panels flat>
    <v-expansion-panel >
      <v-expansion-panel-header>
        header
      </v-expansion-panel-header>
      <v-expansion-panel-content>
        Content
      </v-expansion-panel-content>
    </v-expansion-panel>
  </v-expansion-panels>
```

Answer (score 5):

With Veutify 2 the following css does the job.

```
.v-expansion-panel::before {
   box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Put this lines of code into your CSS:

```
.v-expansion-panel {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks :D